# What is the name for a series of keys in a hash/dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, hash, path, key-value, naming

Is there a name for navigating through a series of keys, one level or more? Similar to a 'path' in a filesystem or URL, is there an agreed upon name for this in key value stores?

example: `object['recent'][0]['high']`

Edit: Apple seems to refer to a "[key path](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE)." Not sure if that's a widely accepted term. Is that a widely accepted term?